# Extract sub-string from given String value using regex

Tags: java, regex, spring, string

I have a requirement where a string needs to be matched and then extract further value from a that string

I will receive a header in request whose value will be a DN name from ssl certificate. Here need to match a specific string 1.2.3.47 in the header and extract remaining text.

Sample String passed to method:
O=ABC Bank Plc/1.2.3.47=ABC12-PQR-121878, CN=7ltM2wQ3bqlDJdBEURGAMq, L=INDIA, C=INDIA, E=xyz@gmail.com

Here is my code:

```
private String extractDN(String dnHeader) {
     if(!ValidatorUtil.isEmpty(dnHeader)){

       String tokens[]=dnHeader.split(",");
       if(tokens[0].contains("1.2.3.47")){

          int index=tokens[0].lastIndexOf("1.2.3.47");
          String id=tokens[0].substring(index+9);
          System.out.println(id);


       }



     }
    return id;
  }
```

Can a regex pattern be used here to match and extract value? Is there any better way to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: So given you input `O=ABC Bank Plc/1.2.3.47=ABC12-PQR-121878, CN=7ltM2wQ3bqlDJdBEURGAMq, L=INDIA, C=INDIA, E=xyz@gmail.com`, what is the expected output? Is it `ABC12-PQR-121878`?

Comment: yes ABC12-PQR-121878 should be the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a pattern and if you know that the value always starts with a forward slash and if followed by one or more digits separated by a dot and then an equals sign, you could use a capturing group:

```
/[0-9](?:\\.[0-9]+)+=([^,]+)
```

- `/` Match `/`
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digit 0-9
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\\.[0-9]+` match `.` and 1+ digits 0-9
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `=` Match `=`
- `([^,]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except a `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pILVpH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FcBjQY)

For example

```
final String regex = "/[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)+=([^,]+)";
final String string = "O=ABC Bank Plc/1.2.3.47=ABC12-PQR-121878, CN=7ltM2wQ3bqlDJdBEURGAMq, L=INDIA, C=INDIA, E=xyz@gmail.com";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
ABC12-PQR-121878
```

---

If you want a more precise match, you could also specify the start of the pattern:

```
\\bO=\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*/[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)+=([^,]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DAZLcr/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But upstream system may or may not include / before 1.2.3.47. Can there be a regex to match 1.2.3.47 and extract value thereafter? I am new to regex. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use [0-9](?:\\.[0-9]+)+=([^,]+) without / as mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @asp008 Sure you can, see https://regex101.com/r/zRCuSK/1 The Java code could look like https://ideone.com/IIYHov